# Use Browser to get GPS-Data and show pop-up and vibrate/play sound in Android

Tags: javascript, android, web, gps, notifications

i would like to program a website using javascript. 
The website has to be able to be contantly checking the gps-chip of an android device.

When specific coordinates match (coordinates given by the remote-server and coordinates given by the gps-chip), the user should get a notification like a sound or a vibration and a pop-up-window with further information.
Like, when the device passes a coffeeshop, the user is alerted, that there is coffee in the area.

It has to be a website, not an app.

Is such a thing possible?

Are there well known examples for services using such websites?

I hope, my question accurate enough, to be answered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, it's all possible from a webpage. use navigator.geolocation.watchPosition, navigator.vibrate(250), and alert('coffee nearby'). keep in mind that with a web page, the phone must be on (screen on), and the page must be loaded and running on the screen in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exanctly the information i needed to start.